# Using regex to selectively extract substrings in R

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following strings:

```
string <- c(
  "DATE_OF_BIRTH_B1",
  "HEIGHT_BABY2",
  "WEIGHT_BABY_3",
  "OTHER_CONDITION_4",
  "OTHER_OPERATION_5"
)
```

How can I use regex in `gsub()` to extract:

- Everything except the trailing underscore up until the number suffixes in the first three strings;
- Nothing from the last two strings.

In other words, my expected `gsub()` output is:

```
"DATE_OF_BIRTH_B", "HEIGHT_BABY", "WEIGHT_BABY"
```

I managed to use `gsub("(.+_B[A-Z]*)_?[0-9]", "\\1", string)` to extract the desired substrings from the first three strings, but it failed to excluded the last two strings.

Could anyone help to correct and improve my regex, with a bit of explanation? Many thanks!

Comment: Do the strings you want to exclude have some kind of communality? Otherwise I don't see how you could exclude them generally. In your example you could e.g. just filter for OTHER. But something similar to that would need to be present

Comment: It is done using alternation with `.+`: `sub("(.+_B[A-Z]*)_?[0-9]|.+", "\\1", string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect `gsub` (or `sub`, usually, in this case, you really should use a `sub` since you only expect a single replacement operation) to return a result of the replacement or an empty string, you need to follow this technique:

```
sub("...(<what_you_want_to_extract>)...|.+", "\\1", x)
```

That is, your regex is before `|` alternation operator that is followed with `.+` that matches any one or more chars as many as possible.

So, in your case, assuming your regex is just what you need and meets all your requirements, you can use

```r
> res <- sub("(.+_B[A-Z]*)_?[0-9]|.+", "\\1", string)
> res
[1] "DATE_OF_BIRTH_B" "HEIGHT_BABY"     "WEIGHT_BABY"     ""                ""
```

If you need to remove empty items, just use

```r
> res[nzchar(res)]
[1] "DATE_OF_BIRTH_B" "HEIGHT_BABY"     "WEIGHT_BABY"
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much for the tips on not to capture anything in alternative strings!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `OTHER` or the suffix.

```
gsub("^OTHER.*|_?[0-9]+$", "", string)
#> [1] "DATE_OF_BIRTH_B"
#> [2] "HEIGHT_BABY"    
#> [3] "WEIGHT_BABY"    
#> [4] ""               
#> [5] ""
```

Or, if you specifically want capture groups, use a non-greedy capture.

```
gsub("(OTHER.*)?(.*?)_?[0-9]", "\\2", string)
#> [1] "DATE_OF_BIRTH_B"
#> [2] "HEIGHT_BABY"    
#> [3] "WEIGHT_BABY"    
#> [4] ""               
#> [5] ""
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solutions! Filtering for "OTHER" is a good tip, but @Wiktor Stribiżew's solution may be more universal?